# Triangle RMS calculate

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, math, power-factor-correction

About BCM PFC current, why I_L RMS value is [image]
this is from [ST document](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00195944-solution-for-designing-a-transition-mode-pfc-preregulator-with-the-l6562a-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

[image]

I try to use rms formula to calculate it, and I also do the research I find the result should be like the below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is different in the case of a PFC. You need to determine the rms value of the waveform across a switching cycle (high frequency) then integrate the whole thing along the mains cycle (low frequency). This is quite complicated but that's the way ST obtained this rms value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this proof will help (it's an AC triangular voltage waveform that is initially calculated but, the same principle applies to a triangular shaped current): -

[image]

But, when the waveform is biased above 0 volts, you need to calculate the RMS value using \$\sqrt{DC^2 + AC^2}\$. In your example, the equivalent DC value is \$V_P\$ hence, the total RMS value is: -

$$\sqrt{V_P^2 + \dfrac{V_P^2}{3}}\hspace{0.5cm} = \hspace{0.5cm} V_P\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{3}}\hspace{0.5cm} = \hspace{0.5cm} V_P\sqrt{\dfrac{4}{3}}\hspace{1cm} = \hspace{0.5cm}\dfrac{2\cdot V_P}{\sqrt3}$$

Comment: Hi Andy, this is different here because of the high-frequency "instantaneous" rms inductor current expression that needs to be integrated along the low-frequency mains cycle.

Comment: @VerbalKint I agree that this is ultimately what is needed but, if you look at the question, I believe it's all about a single triangular cycle and that's what I've derived. See page 9/36 of the ST document.

Comment: Hi @Verbal Kint, 
Could you explain more why you said this is different?

Comment: @Jitter456 at the risk of misrepresenting verbal kint, he's talking about the AC half-sine waveform (where many different "versions" of \$I_{peak}\$ are created throughout the half cycle). And, to full calculate inductor RMS current you have to take all of these into account.

Comment: Oui Andy, this is what I meant by the need to average the "instantaneous" high-frequency rms current along the mains cycle to obtain the total rms current in the PFC inductor. You would also do that for calculating the conduction power loss in the transistor.

Comment: You can have a look at this [document](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8123-D.PDF) published by colleague Joël long time ago. He gave all calculation details for determining these currents. Look at equation (27) which averages the rms current.

Comment: @Andyaka,

Got it, thanks.

Comment: @VerbalKint, 

Do you know the CCM RMS current calculation?
I don't see the document to calculate the CCM calculate.
is it the same?

Comment: You don't see it because the title says *Critical Mode* : ) A quick Google search leads to this [AN](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/InfineonApplicationNote_PFCCCMBoostConverterDesignGuide-AN-v02_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624a56eed8014a62c75a923b05) from Infineon where you have some of the expressions you need.

Comment: @Jitter456 if we are done here you should accept the answer or raise another comment seeking clarification.

Comment: Hi @Andyaka,

I see.